# Test Stack White & WPF: How to enter date value in Xceed DatePicker?

Tags: wpf, coded-ui-tests

I don't see how to enter (or choose) a date value into an Xceed DatePicker. I can retrieve it as ControlType.ComboBox and cast it into a WPFComboBox, but then I don't know how to set a value. Enter() doesn't work, it gives me a "Changes are not allowed while code in running" in Visual Studio.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: Well, in my case, I'm lucky in the fact that each Xceed DataPicker always goes with a WpfEdit too. So in my Test code I just send the date with the WpfEdit.

You should give a try to record your action with the recorder engine to see how to code this.

If you really want some kind of generic function to automate any date picking, I guess you will have to code a function that will goes throw the DataPicker childs controls to be able to point the MouseClick event at each right place...

Comment: Thanks, BenDev! Are you using Stack White?

Comment: No, I'm using Visual Studio Original Test Engine Framework: Coded UI Test

Comment: That requires VS Enterprise which I don't have. Anyway, thanks for your help.